# How can I implement From<Vec<MyType>> for Vec<MyOtherType>?

Tags: rust, traits

I have two identical structs in two different modules:

Module `data` has struct data::Branch:

```rust
#[derive(Debug, Clone, Serialize, Deserialize)]
pub struct Branch {
    pub id: Uuid,
    pub name: String,
    pub parents: Vec<Branch>,
    pub children: Vec<Branch>,
}
```

And module `graphql` has struct graphql::Branch:

```rust
#[derive(Debug, Clone, Serialize, Deserialize)]
pub struct Branch {
    pub id: Uuid,
    pub name: String,
    pub parents: Vec<Branch>,
    pub children: Vec<Branch>,
}
```

I can not figure it out how to implement `impl From<Vec<data::Branch>> for Vec<Branch>` in `graphql` module?

```rust
impl From<data::branch::Branch> for Branch {
    fn from(branch: data::branch::Branch) -> Branch {
        Branch {
            id: branch.id,
            name: branch.name,
            content: branch.name,
            parents: branch.parents.into(),
            children: branch.children.into(),
            created_at: branch.created_at,
            updated_at: branch.updated_at,
        }
    }
}

impl From<Vec<data::branch::Branch>> for Vec<Branch> {
    fn from(_: Vec<data::branch::Branch>) -> Self {
        todo!();
    }
}
```

I have faced this error and don't know how to handle it.

```
error[E0117]: only traits defined in the current crate can be implemented for types defined outside of the crate
  --> src/graphql/branch/branch.rs:64:1
   |
64 | impl From<Vec<data::branch::Branch>> for Vec<Branch> {
   | ^^^^^-------------------------------^^^^^-----------
   | |    |                                   |
   | |    |                                   `Vec` is not defined in the current crate
   | |    `Vec` is not defined in the current crate
   | impl doesn't use only types from inside the current crate
   |
   = note: define and implement a trait or new type instead
```

Comment: The short answer is you can't due to the orphan rules. I recommend you just use the same type in both cases. If neither is a better owner maybe create a `types` module for it?

Comment: Just make the conversion a free function instead of using the `From` trait.

Comment: Related if not a duplicate: [Does Rust implement From<Vec<T>> for Vec<U> if I have already implemented From<T> for U?](/q/65328977/2189130) or even [In Rust, how to define a generic function for converting Vec<T> to Vec<U>](/q/70014181/2189130)

Answer (score 0):

As I understand now simple generic function can easily handle such case. Thank you @kmdreko for your help.

It works for me. The only problem is that the compiler suggests implementing `From<Vec<data::Branch>> for Vec<Branch>`, but you can't do it, and this is a little bit confusing if you don't know rust well)

[rust playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&code=mod%20data%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%23%5Bderive(Debug%2C%20Clone%2C%20Default)%5D%0A%20%20%20%20pub%20struct%20Branch%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20pub%20id%3A%20String%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20pub%20name%3A%20String%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20pub%20parents%3A%20Vec%3CBranch%3E%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20pub%20children%3A%20Vec%3CBranch%3E%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0A%23%5Bderive(Debug%2C%20Clone)%5D%0Apub%20struct%20Branch%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20pub%20id%3A%20String%2C%0A%20%20%20%20pub%20name%3A%20String%2C%0A%20%20%20%20pub%20parents%3A%20Vec%3CBranch%3E%2C%0A%20%20%20%20pub%20children%3A%20Vec%3CBranch%3E%2C%0A%7D%0A%0Aimpl%20From%3Cdata%3A%3ABranch%3E%20for%20Branch%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20fn%20from(branch%3A%20data%3A%3ABranch)%20-%3E%20Branch%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Branch%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20id%3A%20branch.id.clone()%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20name%3A%20branch.name.clone()%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20parents%3A%20convert_from_vec(branch.parents.clone())%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20children%3A%20convert_from_vec(branch.children.clone())%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Afn%20convert_from_vec%3CT%2C%20U%3E(v%3A%20Vec%3CU%3E)%20-%3E%20Vec%3CT%3E%0Awhere%0A%20%20%20%20T%3A%20From%3CU%3E%2C%0A%7B%0A%20%20%20%20v.into_iter().map(T%3A%3Afrom).collect()%0A%7D%0A%0Afn%20main()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20let%20branch%20%3D%20data%3A%3ABranch%3A%3Adefault()%3B%0A%20%20%20%20let%20branch%3A%20Branch%20%3D%20branch.into()%3B%0A%7D).

```rust
mod data {
    #[derive(Debug, Clone, Default)]
    pub struct Branch {
        pub id: String,
        pub name: String,
        pub parents: Vec<Branch>,
        pub children: Vec<Branch>,
    }
}

#[derive(Debug, Clone)]
pub struct Branch {
    pub id: String,
    pub name: String,
    pub parents: Vec<Branch>,
    pub children: Vec<Branch>,
}

impl From<data::Branch> for Branch {
    fn from(branch: data::Branch) -> Branch {
        Branch {
            id: branch.id.clone(),
            name: branch.name.clone(),
            parents: convert_from_vec(branch.parents.clone()),
            children: convert_from_vec(branch.children.clone()),
        }
    }
}

fn convert_from_vec<T, U>(v: Vec<U>) -> Vec<T>
where
    T: From<U>,
{
    v.into_iter().map(T::from).collect()
}

fn main() {
    let branch = data::Branch::default();
    let branch: Branch = branch.into();
}
```